# Methods to determine integration limits?

Tags: calculus, integration

So this is one thing that I'm having some issues with. I don't understand how to determine integration limits.

> First example:
>   [image]

At the above example the correct integration limit is $\int^2_0$ which just doesn't make sense. I mean yes $x=2$ does make sense, but where did they take $0$ from?

> Second example: [image]

If someone has a good/safe way to determine limits, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I both cases you have been given 3 curves that enclose your region.  (a line is a curve, the x axis is a curve.)

Sketch them as best you can.

Find the points of intersection between each pair of curves.

In the first one.

[image]

The picture does not need to be precise.  But it does help to know if the curves are generally upward sloping, downward sloping, convex, etc.

Where does y = 1 intersect f(x)?

$1 = \frac {2e^x}{1+e^x}\\
1+e^x = 2e^x\\
e^x = 1\\
x = 0$

your limits are $x\in [0,2]$

$V = \pi \int_0^2 (f(x))^2\ dx$

In the second one, you have already been provided with a picture.

Solve for $f(x) = 0, g(x) = 0, f(x) = g(x)$

$f(x) = 0\\
e^{2x} - 6e^x = 0$
We only need the find where the numerator equals 0.

$e^{2x} = 6e^x$
Take the log of both sides

$2x = x+\ln 6\\
x = \ln 6$

$g(x) = 0$ at $x = 0$

$f(x) = g(x)\\
\frac {e^{2x} -6e^x}{e^x +2} = 2 - 2e^x\\
e^{2x} -6e^x = (e^x +2)(2-2e^x)\\
e^{2x} -6e^x = -2e^{2x} -2e^x+ 4\\
3e^{2x} - 8e^x - 4 = 0\\
u = e^x\\
3u^2 - 4u - 4 = 0\\
(3u + 2)(u-2) = 0$

There are two solutions to the polynomial, but since $e^x>0,$ we can discard one.

$e^x = 2\\
x = \ln 2$

You are going to need to break this integral into two.  If you think about Riemann sums and the rectangles you need to add, you will have some rectangles with a vertical range from [f(x), 0] and some which will be [g(x), 0]

$\int_0^{\ln 2} (0-g(x)) \ dx + \int_{\ln 2}^{\ln 6} (0-f(x)) \ dx$

Answer (score 1):

Think about what x is if you set y=0 in your equation? And graphically rotating the object will only yield the part between x=0 to x=2.

Answer (score 0):

a) Point (0, 1) is the intersection of $f(x)$ and $y = 2$ graphs. The projection of the enclosed area onto the $x$-axis is the segment $[0, 2]$. Therefore, the integration limits are $\int_0^2$.

b) The enclosed area consists of the triangles $ABH$ and $BCH$.

$A (0, 0)$, $B(\log 2, -2)$, $C(\log 6, 0)$, $H (\log 2, 0)$.

Therefore:

$V = -\int\limits_{0}^{\log 2} g(x)\,dx - \int\limits_{\log 2}^{\log 6} f(x)\,dx.$

[image]